# GitHub forum/helpdesk solution

Tags: social-media, forum

Our open source software website is migrating from Redmine to GitHub (pages, wiki, issues) and the only missing thing is *Forum/Discussions*. GitHub does not have such feature yet and allows only static pages generation.

We really would like to support our users using forum. I was thinking about disqus.com like engine that can be attached to website, but what I have found offers only comments support for specific page/topic on website, they don't have ability for user to create a thread/topic like on forums.

Question: Is there any 3rd party solution which will support forum/helpdesk like mechanism without requiring and server side installation and can be embedded in pure html? Also would be great if such engine support social networking authorization (like disqus).

P.S.: What alternatives would you recommend for user support?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one: http://tal.ki/? Only thing you need to do is include a JS script, and Github allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Github does have this feature.